# Uploading a bos file from the portal

Tags: bonita

I'm following along with the getting started tutorial (Travel Requests) and I am at the part where it says to export the project from within bonita studio and then upload it as a resource in the portal. However when I go to resources in the coolbar and click add, it only allows me to upload zip files. Whats up with that?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, it said to export the page from the UI designer, not from Bonita Studio. Exporting from the UI designer does indeed create a zip file.